# How to estimate minimum sample size to achieve a certain confidence interval?

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-deviation, sample-size, standard-error

The title of this question is a bit general. Allow me to elaborate.

## Context

- I'm measuring a biological parameter (*BP*) of different subjects.
- For each subject, *BP* follows a normal distribution, with an unknown standard deviation
- The average and **standard deviation is dependent on the subjects** - some subjects might have larger or smaller variance.

## What I have

- I have a database from a previous study where I measured a couple hundred of subjects
- Each subject was measured at least 10 times

## Goal

- For a new study, I want to get a number of measurements *N*, required to achieve, at least, a 95 % confidence level that the real average of the subject is within the sample average $\bar{x} \pm \delta$ [units].

**How can I achieve this?**

My thoughts:

- I could estimate one standard deviation value for each subject (based on 10+ measurements for each subject).
- Then, I could calculate the **average of all the standard deviations** $(\sigma_{avg})$.
- I would use the average standard deviation to calculate N:

$$
( CI_{95\%} = \bar{x} \pm \delta \:, CI_{95\%} = \bar{x} \pm 1.96 \cdot {\sigma \over \sqrt{N}})
$$
$$
\implies \sqrt{N} = 1.96 \cdot {\sigma_{avg} \over \delta}
$$

But I'm not sure about this logic, and specifically what is the validity and implications of averaging standard deviations.

Comment: There are different methods to evaluate your sample size that depends on many parameters such as type of test, expected power, margin of errors, etc... If you use R, you might want to have a look at the pwr.t.test function

Comment: Since you have data from a previous experiment ... if you assume future data will be somewhat similar, you can resample fron that dataset for various n, fit models, calculate confidence intervals, and see what n you need to get CIs of satisfactory length ...

Comment: @Pitouille I'm sorry, but I cannot understand what you mean... I might be missing some fundamental knowledge here. I don't see how a t-test could help me in this case. I don't use R - my question it's not a matter of the library I'm using to apply a method, but more about the fundamentals: what method should I follow in my case and why. Thank you for your help

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I think I understand what you mean. With the given assumptions, you're suggesting that I would run a data analysis of my current data set. I would simulate n = 2 to 10, randomly selecting the points for each subject, and then determine the deviation of these sampled averages vary as a function of n. When the deviation is within my CI, that would tell me the n I would need. Did I understand correctly? While it seems a a logical approach to me, it also seems a bit of hacking approach instead of a clean statistical approach. Is this an unfounded fear?

Comment: @cinico, This page https://statisticsbyjim.com/hypothesis-testing/sample-size-power-analysis/  explains (much better than I could do) with few jargon or formulas the different parameters that you could consider in determining the sample size. Please not that the R function pwr.t.test is not really for t-test but for computing power of tests as well as sample size.

Comment: @Pitouille But if I understand correctly, a power test is useful to define the sample size to test a certain null-hypothesis. In my case, I do not have a hypothesis that I want to test. Or is there a way that I can frame my problem in such way that I have null-hypothesis?

Comment: Confidence Interval and p-value are related. In one case you are looking for information about the likely range of the effect while in the other case you are trying to reject the null hypothesis (that states that there is no effect). A confidence level of 0.95 is equivalent to a significance level of 0.05. However, to go back to your question, I feel your problem statement might be incorrect... or I do not understand it correctly.

Comment: Is N here the number of observations for each unit, with N=10 in you pilot study?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov N is number of observations per subject. In the pilot study I have at least N=10 for each of 200+ subjects.